# Mysql- Get dates between from date and to date

Tags: mysql

I have a table **tbl_patient**: contain `from_date, to_date, patient_name` and `gender`.

```
from_date    to_date      patient_name   gender

2017-06-10   2017-06-13   AAA            Male
2017-06-08   2017-06-11   BBB            Female
2017-06-13   2017-06-15   CCC            Male
```

I have to create a new table **tbl_details** from **tbl_patient**, which contain date(between `from_date` and `to_date` from `tbl_patient`), total_number of patients in that day, number of male and number of female

```
date          patients    Male    Female

2017-06-10    2           1       1
2017-06-11    2           1       1
2017-06-12    1           1       0
2017-06-13    2           2       0
2017-06-08    1           0       1
2017-06-09    1           0       1    
2017-06-14    1           1       0
2017-06-15    1           1       0
```

My problem is I am unable to write query to find the dates between from_date and to_date

```
I tried 

SELECT DATE_ADD( MIN(from_date), interval @num := @num+1 day) AS date_sequence, 
tbl_patient.* FROM tbl_patient
HAVING DATE_ADD(MIN(from_date), interval @num day) <= MAX(to_date)
```

But no luck..

Please someone can help me..

Comment: what's the logic between patients and date in your expected output ? why there are 2 patients on 10-06, 11-6 and only 1 on 12-06 ?

Comment: Are you looking for a query that gives you no of patients divided in males/females per day, between from and to?

Comment: Can u echo your current query here

Comment: Simplest thing to do is probably to create a calendar table, and then inner join that to your current table on the range matching.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: use between instead of having   here is a demo query with between    SELECT * from Orders 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN('1996-04-07') AND ('1996-09-07');

Comment: @PrabhatG, 10-06 and 11-06 have two rows in tbl_patient table(ie, two patients) and 12-06 have only one row

Answer (score 0):

**Table:**

```
create table tbl_patient (
    from_date date, 
    to_date date,
    patient_name varchar(45),
    gender varchar(45)
)
```

**Insert values:**

```
insert into tbl_patient values ('2017-06-10','2017-06-13','AAA','Male');
insert into tbl_patient values ('2017-06-08','2017-06-11','BBB','Female');
insert into tbl_patient values ('2017-06-13','2017-06-15','CCC','Male');
```

**Query:**

```
 set @mindate = (select min(from_date) - interval 1 day as mindate from tbl_patient);
set @maxdate = (select max(to_date) as mindate from tbl_patient);
select date_value, count(patient_name), count(case when gender = 'male' then 1 end) male, 
count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) female 

from (select @startDate := @startDate + Interval 1 day as date_value
from (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 
    union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 
    union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
    union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4,
(SELECT @startDate := @mindate ) t5 
where @startDate < @maxdate ) generateCalendar

left join tbl_patient on date_value between from_date and to_date
group by date_value;
```

You can generate calender using query as well. Just find min and max date.

Note: min date should be 1 day less.

Comment: @next2u Updated answer. Let me know it is helpful or not.

Comment: what is `generateCalendar`? How to use this?

Comment: @next2u GenerateCalender is nothing but generating rows with all the dates between your start date and enddate. Have you executed above query with your data ?

Comment: @next2u Could you please tell me what is data types of all column present in tbl_patients.

Comment: from_date and  to_date are date, name is varchar and gender is enum('Male', 'Female')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146616/discussion-between-fahad-anjum-and-next2u).